# NumPy array element not getting updated

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a NumPy array as follows:

```
supp = np.array([['A', '5', '0'], ['B', '3', '0'], ['C', '4', '0'], ['D', '1', '0'], ['E', '2', '0']])
```

Now, I want to update the row[2] as row[1]/6.
I'm using..

`for row in supp:
    row[2] = row[1].astype(int) / 6`

But row[2] seems to remain unaffected..

```
>>> supp
array([['A', '5', '0'],
   ['B', '3', '0'],
   ['C', '4', '0'],
   ['D', '1', '0'],
   ['E', '2', '0']],  
  dtype='<U1')
```

I'm using Python 3.5.2 and NumPy 1.11.1.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: Take a look at the result of `supp[0,0] = 5/6`

Comment: Trying to put strings and numbers in the same array is a bad idea. Depending on what you're doing, Pandas might have more suitable tools for your use case, or it might be better to just get rid of the first column and use an array of float dtype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that an `np.array` has only one type which is automatically assumed to be strings `supp.dtype == '|S1'` since your input contains only strings of length `1`. So numpy will automatically convert your updated inputs to strings of length `1`, `'0'`s in your case. Force it to be of generic type `object` and then it will be able to have both strings and ints or floats or anything else:

```
supp = np.array([['A', '5', '0'], ['B', '3', '0'], ['C', '4', '0'], ['D', '1', '0'], ['E', '2', '0']])
supp = supp.astype(object)

for row in supp:
    row[2] = int(row[1]) / 6
```

result:

```
[['A' '5' 0.8333333333333334]
 ['B' '3' 0.5]
 ['C' '4' 0.6666666666666666]
 ['D' '1' 0.16666666666666666]
 ['E' '2' 0.3333333333333333]]
```

alternatively you can also use the `dtype` `'|Sn'` with larger value of `n`:

```
supp = np.array([['A', '5', '0'], ['B', '3', '0'], ['C', '4', '0'], ['D', '1', '0'], ['E', '2', '0']])
supp = supp.astype('|S5')

for row in supp:
    row[2] = int(row[1]) / 6
```

result:

```
[['A' '5' '0.833']
 ['B' '3' '0.5']
 ['C' '4' '0.666']
 ['D' '1' '0.166']
 ['E' '2' '0.333']]
```

and in this case you are still having only strings if that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Learned a new thing today. :)

Comment: Me too! ;) BTW, I totally second  user2357112 's comment. You should probably think about it... Using `dtype=object` might be convenient but you'll loose a lot of speedup on numerical computations, which is usually the point of using numpy.